# column copy and paste in row

Tags: vim

I have a file with follow content:

```
    sensor_write_reg(client,0x57,0x00);
    sensor_write_reg(client,0x58,0x00);
    sensor_write_reg(client,0x59,0x00);
    sensor_write_reg(client,0xfe,0x00);
    sensor_write_reg(client,0x46,0x00);
```

I want to column copy the following text to a new file:

```
struct reg reg_table[] =
{
// paste here
}

int a;
int b;
int c;
// ...

the following content expected:
struct reg reg_table[] =
{
0xfe,0x01   
0x54,0x11
0x55,0x03
0x56,0x00
0x57,0x00
0x58,0x00
0x59,0x00
0xfe,0x00
0x46,0x00
}

int a;
int b;
int c;
// ...
```

In the source file, I type CTRL+v to enter column mode, select and copy.
Type CTRL+W to enter the destination file, and type p to paste.
However, the pasted content overrides the following statements. That's not I want.

```
0xfe,0x01
0x54,0x11}
0x55,0x03int a;
0x56,0x00int b;
0x57,0x00int c;
0x58,0x00
```

Is the any way to paste it in row mode, in a number of new lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **always** paste something linewise you can use the `:put` command.

```
:put
```

If you want to convert to characterwise or blockwise you can use the `setreg()` function as shown in this [vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Unconditional_linewise_or_characterwise_paste) or use this plugin, [UnconditionalPaste](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355).

Comment: @soul2003 Glad you like it. I find it very useful when pasting from the system clipboard, `:pu *`

Answer (score 0):

Blockwise selection doesn't work like linewise selection.

You are copying text from 6 lines so you have to free 6 lines for pasting. Try `6O<CR>p`

Comment: Thanks! How to insert 6 blank lines after the cursor? It's better not leave the command mode.

Comment: @soul2003, Vim's commands often follow the same pattern: lowercase letter for commands that apply to the right/down/next direction and UPPERCASE for commands that apply to the left/up/previous direction. At least in a western context. For example: `fx`goes to the next `x` character to the right while `Fx` goes to the previous `x` to the left. Here we use `O` to add a line **before** the current one, what command shall we use to add a line **after**? Also you can use `:put=''` or `:put!=''` if you don't want to leave normal mode. `:help :put`.

Answer (score 0):

You also could try a macro; after some trying, I found this one:

```
y:tabe^MP:%s/^.*\(0x\x\+,0x\x\+\).*$/\1/^MVggy:tabclose!^M^Wjp
```

(the `^M` and `^W` are carriage return and control-W)

The setup of your vim would be...

- one tab with two windows, horz splitted (via C-W S)
- the sensor_write_reg-stuff in the upper window,
- the paste here-source code in the lower one.
- lower window: got to line "paste here"
- upper window: visual select (now with capital V) the lines you want
- then press @q (if the macro is saved to q; or just type the commands on the fly...) and let the magic happen...

what happens here?

- ```
  y
  ```

  we yank the text
- ```
  :tabe^MP
  ```

  and open a new tab with an empty buffer, paste the text
- (caution: if you have an unnamed buffer, this will not work)
- ```
  :%s/^.(0x\x+,0x\x+).$/\1/
  ```

  here we filter: only two hex-digits, seperated by a comma, will survive.
- ```
  Vggy:tabclose!^M
  ```

  yank everything, close the buffer (without saving)
- (now we are back to the first tab, still in the upper window)
- ```
  ^Wjp
  ```

  move one window down, and paste.

Finally you could use a `kD` to delete the "paste here"-line...

Comment: Yes, it's what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: somewhere near the top of this post you may find a check mark that likes to be clicked on :)